# Static memory pool object per Class type

Tags: c++

I am trying to design memory pool based allocation for my classes in C++ .Currently I have the following operator overloads:

```
class Foo{

    public:
     Foo(){}

     void* operator new(size_t nbytes, Pool& pool)
     {

         return    pool.alloc(nbytes);
     }

     void operator delete(void* p)
    {

         pool->dealloc(p);   

   }

};
```

Now,I don't want to pass the Pool object as parameter into new.Also I must somehow reference it for dtor to deallocate from it when it gets called.I thought of initializing Pool as static before the class declaration like this:

```
   class Foo{

     static boost::pool<> pool ;
     public:
     Foo()
     {

     }

     void* operator new(size_t nbytes)
     {

         return    pool.alloc(nbytes);
     }

     void operator delete(void* p)
    {

         pool.dealloc(p);   

    }


 };
```

**In .cpp:**

```
    boost::pool<> Foo::pool(sizeof(Foo)) ;//preallocates N * sizeof(Foo) bytes
```

Is this right way to do this?Will the 'pool' be always constructed before the first instance of Foo created?

UPDATE:

This approach doesn't work.Looks like the pool has no allocated memory when Foo is begin created.

Answer (score 3):

An object declared `static` in a class is basically a global object with a funny name. The rule for global objects is that they will be created before the start of `main` and destroyed after the end of `main`, in an unspecified order. The only guarantee is that if a specific compilation unit (i.e. a .cpp file) there are two global objects `A` and `B` and `A` appears before `B` then `A` will be constructed before `B`.

So if you don't have any global instance of `Foo` things are ok, otherwise you have a problem.

The common solution is to use a static function returning a reference to a local static object instead of using a global object, i.e.

```
class Foo {
    static Pool& pool() {
        static Pool p;
        return p;
    }
    ...
};
```

this solves the problem because static objects inside functions are going to be constructed the first time the function is called. You only have to be careful about multithreading in this case (i.e. if there is a risk that two threads will enter the static function at the same time).

With C++11 not even threads are a problem because the initialization is guaranteed to work safely (if two threads calls the function at the same time one will be made to wait until the other completes the initialization of the singleton).

Comment: Really...How I haven't thought about it!